# How to write One-Time Pad cipher in Python

Tags: python, encryption, one-time-pad

Based on Wikipedia, [One-Time Pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) is an encryption technique that cannot be cracked. How to implement One-Time Pad encryption in Python?

Comment: That's not completely true. It cannot be cracked if used correctly. If a one-time pad is used over and over then it can be broken using frequency analysis.

Comment: The name suggests it should be used ONE TIME, so this is the base assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example implementation

```py
def encrypt(pad, secret):
    return ''.join([chr(ord(c) ^ ord(secret[i])) for i, c in enumerate(pad[:len(secret)])])
```

Now you can use it to encrypt your messages. Remember the `pad` size should be at least the size of the secret:

```py
secret = 'i am a secret'
pad = '33116f14-9b6f-42c6-9636-3dbd31c0548d'
enc = encrypt(pad, secret)
```

And you can decipher it with the same function:

```py
assert secret == encrypt(pad, enc)
```

Comment: you could really use `zip` here